# How to Initialize Matrix from input - Python

Tags: python, matrix, input

i need to implement a program that initialize matrix with input elements and will print the matrix in rows and columns, any ideas?

```
def initializeMatrix(m):
    rows = 2
    columns = 2
    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(columns):
            num = input('Insert Number: ')
            m.append(num)
   print(m)
```

Comment: Since you use .append(), you are just making a list of numbers like `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @GilbertAllen, this sequence can be treated as a two-by-two matrix _while internally it'll be a mere flat list_.

Comment: @ForceBru Ok, I was just unsure whether that was the op's intent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrix `m` is initialized with your code, which is correct.

```
for a in range(rows):
    for b in range(columns):
        print(m[a*columns + b], " ", end='')
    print()
```

What's more, your approach is better than using a list of lists since in your case the values of a matrix will be held in a contiguous block of memory, thus providing faster access to them.

---

### Edit regarding your latest comments

Certainly, you can initialize a list of lists like this:

```
rows=2
columns=2
m=[]
for a in range(rows):
    m.append(list())
    for b in range(columns):
        m[a].append(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Then you output it like this:

```
for row in m:
    for number in row:
        print(number," ", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: yes, but i need to initialize a list of list with input keyboard element.

Comment: @RaffaeleDavid, your approach is _correct_, no need to deal with a list of lists since accessing data from it will be _pretty slow_.

Comment: ok i understand, but i want to initialize a matrix like this: [[16,3,2,13],[5,10,11,8],[9,6,7,12],[4,15,14,1]]

Comment: @RaffaeleDavid, okay, I've edited my answer to include a version that uses a list of lists